# Python sys.argv works whenn running .py file, but errors after cx_Freeze

Tags: python, urllib, sys

So, I have this small piece of WIP code.

```
import sys
import urllib


def download(url,file_name):
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,file_name)

if "-r" in sys.argv[1:]:
    print("Do this")
    print("gave: "+sys.argv[2])
if sys.argv[3]:
    print("and: "+sys.argv[3])
else:
    print("some message")
```

when I run this from cmd with

> main.py -r sth sth

It works as expected, I get the outputs. I then apply cx_Freeze on it, using this buildfile

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"]}

# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a
# console application).
base = None


setup(  name = "offit",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "offit package and dependencie management",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("main.py", base=base)])
```

When I try to run the .exe produced from cmd, I get this error:

```
C:\Users\Compaq\Documents\Programming\offit\build\exe.win32-3.4>main.exe -r sth
sth
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 27
, in <module>
exec(code, m.__dict__)
File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
File "c:\python\32-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2214, in _find_a
nd_load
File "c:\python\32-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2203, in _find_a
nd_load_unlocked
File "c:\python\32-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1191, in _load_u
nlocked
File "c:\python\32-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1161, in _load_b
ackward_compatible
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_fix_up_module'

C:\Users\Compaq\Documents\Programming\offit\build\exe.win32-3.4>
```

What could this mean and how to solve it? Seems to be the urllib import line....

Comment: Must be an issue with cx_freeze, it works with pyinstaller main.py --onefile.

Answer (score 0):

read the 
https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/issue/81/python-34-venv-importlib-attributeerror
and 
[cx_freeze doesn't work in my script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25342236/cx-freeze-doesnt-work-in-my-script)

install unoffical cx_freeze from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cx_freeze