# cx_freeze doesn't work in my script

Tags: python-3.x, cx-freeze

I freeze a script using cx_freeze (4.3.1) in python 3.4.

The script works perfectly running in IDLE. It uses tkinter, re, and reportlab to create a pdf form.

Then the following error occurrs when I run the exe.

```
    PS C:\Python34\build\exe.win32-3.4> .\CREEPING_cx_freeze.exe  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 27, in <module>
    exec(code, m.__dict__)
 File "CREEPING_cx_freeze.py", line 6, in <module>
 File "c:\python\32-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2214, in _find_and_load
 File "c:\python\32-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2203, in _find_and_load_unlocked
 File "c:\python\32-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
File "c:\python\32-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
```

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_fix_up_module'

It looks like everything is working. Everything is created in the build folder, but the compiled executable does not work.

I tried searching for a solution but did not find any. Could somebody help me with this?

Comment: Is that the full text of the traceback? If not, please [edit] your question and add **everything** that prints out when you run the `.exe`.

Comment: Excuse me. This is the full error message.

Comment: Try installing the latest version of cx_Freeze from [this site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cx_freeze).

Comment: Thanks. I tried but a message of error "no python 3.4 installed" shows when I did it. I installed cx-Freeze as: pip install cx_Freeze

Answer (score 0):

I´m using win 8 64 bits

Wrong version installed.

pip installs 64 bits but it doesn,t work.

running the 32bits version...works

Comment: the cx_Freeze version needs to match your Python version, and you can have a 32-bit Python installed on a 64-bit OS.